# How to give rights to a user for another pc in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

How can we give rights to a user for another pc to perform TFS activities.? One user has forgotten his password, so we want to login to his pc using some other credentials and check in his changes. Forgot password is the option, but no luck with TFS admins because account is setup by TFS admins. Basically it is to give a user rights for multiple pcs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are speaking specifically about version control? Are you using TFVC?
In TFVC you can use the [tf workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspace-command) command to change the owner of a workspace and you will be able to see the information such as binding paths etc.

In either git or TFVC you should have the source available on the hard disk and you should be able to see what changes where made and not yet committed.